# empty pandas.Series does not provide .empty = True

Tags: python, pandas

Could someone please explain this strange behavior?

```
In [1]: import pandas

In [2]: test_series = pandas.Series

In [3]: test_series.empty
Out[3]: <property at 0x10b45b048>

In [4]: test_series.empty == True
Out[4]: False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not creating an empty Series; you're just giving the name `test_series` to the Series type itself.  And the `empty` property itself isn't equal to True.

Instead, you want to make an instance of Series:

```
>>> test_series = pandas.Series()
>>> test_series
Series([], dtype: float64)
>>> test_series.empty
True
```